# Convert a POJO to Tree structure in Java 8 for representation of data in hierarchical structure

Tags: java, collections, java-8, spring-data-jpa, treeview

I have a `List<CropDetailDto>` returned by **Hibernate Projection** of a native query in **postgresql**.

I want to represent this in a *hierarchical / tree* format to send it as response.

I used multiple nested `Collectors.groupingBy` on `List<CropDetailDto>`

```
public Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, List<CropDetailDto>>>> findCropDetails() {
        List<CropDetailDto> cropdetails = cropRepository.getCropDetails();
        return cropdetails.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(CropDetailDto::getCropName, Collectors.groupingBy(
                v -> v.getVarietyName() == null ? "undefined" : v.getVarietyName(),
                Collectors.groupingBy(m -> m.getSubVarietyName() == null ? "undefined" : m.getSubVarietyName()))));
    }
```

I was somehow able to represent the data in this format.

```
{
  "Tomato": {
    "Red Tomato": {
      "Red Tomato 1 quality": [
        {
          "cropName": "Tomato",
          "varietyName": "Red Tomato",
          "subVarietyName": "Red Tomato 1 quality",
          "varietyId": 1002,
          "cropId": 1,
          "subVarietyId": 1003           //cropDetailDto is again represented 
                                          //at the leaf level
        }
      ],
      "Red Tomato 2 quality": [
        {
          "cropName": "Tomato",
          "varietyName": "Red Tomato",
          "subVarietyName": "Red Tomato 2 quality",
          "varietyId": 1002,
          "cropId": 1,
          "subVarietyId": 1004
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "Brinjal": {
    "undefined": {
      "undefined": [
        {
          "cropName": "Brinjal",
          "varietyName": null,
          "subVarietyName": null,
          "varietyId": null,
          "cropId": 8,
          "subVarietyId": null
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

However, this representation has `undefined` as the key, since it threw NPE for null keys.

I would like to represent the same data in a much cleaner format.

Something like this:

```
{
  "Tomato": {
    "Red Tomato": [
      "Red Tomato 1 quality",
      "Red Tomato 2 quality"
    ]
  },
  "Brinjal": {}
}
```

i.e., 
if there is a null key I would like it to move to next entry.

I recently started using java 8, I am looking for a concise way to achieve the above structure.

CropDetailDto:

```
public interface CropDetailDto {

    Long getCropId();

    String getCropName();

    Long getVarietyId();

    String getVarietyName();

    Long getSubVarietyId();

    String getSubVarietyName();
}
```

The resulting return type can also be a simple `HashMap<String, Object>`. 
Also , if it is not possible to achieve this using ***Java 8 features***, kindly provide a way to implement this without **java 8**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Collectors.mapping()` instead of the last `Collectors.groupingBy()`:

```
public Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> findCropDetails() {
    List<CropDetailDto> cropdetails = cropRepository.getCropDetails();
    return cropdetails.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(CropDetailDto::getCropName,
            Collectors.groupingBy(v -> v.getVarietyName() == null ? "undefined" : v.getVarietyName(),
                    Collectors.mapping(m -> m.getSubVarietyName() == null ? "undefined" : m.getSubVarietyName(),
                            Collectors.toList()))));
}
```

This will return the following map:

```
{
    "Tomato": {
        "Red Tomato": [
            "Red Tomato 1 quality", 
            "Red Tomato 2 quality"
        ]
    }, 
    "Brinjal": {
        "undefined": [
            "undefined"
        ]
    }
}
```

To remove the `null` values from the result you can use `Collectors.filtering()` and modify the above code a bit:

```
public Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> findCropDetails() {
    List<CropDetailDto> cropdetails = cropRepository.getCropDetails();
    return cropdetails.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(CropDetailDto::getCropName,
            Collectors.filtering(v -> v.getVarietyName() != null, Collectors.groupingBy(CropDetailDto::getVarietyName,
                    Collectors.filtering(m -> m.getSubVarietyName() != null, Collectors.mapping(CropDetailDto::getSubVarietyName,
                            Collectors.toList()))))));
}
```

Using this the final result will look like this:

```
{
    "Tomato": {
        "Red Tomato": [
            "Red Tomato 1 quality", 
            "Red Tomato 2 quality"
        ]
    }, 
    "Brinjal": {}
}
```

Comment: your solution eliminated the leaf -
`"undefined": [
      {
          "cropName": "Brinjal",
          "varietyName": null,
          "subVarietyName": null,
          "varietyId": null,
          "cropId": 8,
          "subVarietyId": null
        }`


However, 
I do not wish to use `undefined` as the key. If the key is `null`, the code should `continue` to next loop.
If the subVariety is null I want empty brackets. `{}`

Comment: @MohammedIdris Yes you are right. forgot to deal with that. I updated my answer and added an extended solution, which removes the `null` values.